# How to validate textbox value while user enters and display error message?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have to code for a method that validates whether the string that saves name contains alphabets only, no numbers. The validation of textbox values should apply when the user enters by  textchanged event before submitting the form and display an error message of red color on the label. My code works but the problem is when I enter a numeric number in text box, the label displays error which stays even when I delete the text box value and enter the alphabetic string.

I have declared a method which assign error string to label, and is called if regular expression does not match with the text box input, during text changed event.

```
public void Validator()
{
    Calculate_Salary.Enabled = false;
    label4.Text = "Please enter only alphabetical letters";
}

private void _Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex("/^[A-Za-z]+$/");
    string name = _Name.Text;
    if (pattern.IsMatch(name))
    {
        Calculate_Salary.Enabled = true;
        label4.Text = "";

    }
    else
    {
        Validator();
    }
}
```

[image: GUI]

Comment: What UI are you using?  WinForms, WPF, or UWP or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Looks like web forms given the event.

Comment: Instead of setting `Enabled`, try changing color

Comment: If you disable that `TextBox`  how you are going to enable it again ?

Comment: Going by the method name, it looks like the textbox, `_Name` is not being disabled, but rather `Calculate_Salary`, which I assume is a button that signals the start of a calculation. And also, the label text, which seems to be what the issue is, is not re-set to a non-error message when the name matches the pattern, never replacing the error message.

Comment: The next step would be to set label4.text = ""; after calculate_salary.enable = true;

Comment: `private void _Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` this is not a WPF event handler. This looks like WinForms. Be clear about the platform, the solution to a problem can change a lot. Also, you can prevent someone from entering chars other than letters filtering the input in the KeyDown event. Pasting strings is another matter, not much different anyway. The Validate event is there for this reason.

Comment: Another thing, take a look at the [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) class. I think this is what is missing in your validation procedure.

Comment: @Uyur99 have you tried `textbox.LostFocus event` ? I think this should do your purpose

Comment: May be the validation code is wrong idk

Comment: @Uyur99 Try setting the label value to: `label4.Text = string.empty;` or you could set the visibillity to false: `label4.Visible = false;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Regex` comparison is wrong try this code:

```
public void Validator()
{
    Calculate_Salary.Enabled = false;
    label4.Text = "Please enter only alphabetical letters";
}

private void _Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = "";
    string name = _Name.Text;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        Calculate_Salary.Enabled = true;
    else
        Validator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the textbox before you validate:

```
public void Validator()
{
    Calculate_Salary.Enabled = false;
    label4.Text = "Please enter only alphabetical letters";
}
private void _Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = "";
    Regex pattern = new Regex("/^[A-Za-z]+$/");
    string name = _Name.Text;
    if (pattern.IsMatch(name))
    {
        Calculate_Salary.Enabled = true;

    }
    else
    {
        Validator();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Regex("/^[A-Za-z]+$/") does match when the text box is empty so it will still display en error. You need to add an option for when the textbox is empty and than Calculate_Salary.Enabled = false but you don't display an error

Answer (score 0):

I changed the validation code. It seems to work now.

```
private void _Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = string.Empty;

    string name = _Name.Text;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(_Name.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$") || _Name.Text=="")
    {
        Calculate_Salary.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Calculate_Salary.Enabled = false;
        label4.Text = Validator();
    }
}
```